# Rate Limit API Calls to Shopify API with Django on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, shopify

I am trying to use the Shopify API from my Django app hosted on Google App Engine.

For my local single threaded scripts I am using a [modified version of this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511490-implementation-of-the-token-bucket-algorithm/) to make sure that I don't go over Shopify's rate limit:

```
# Setup local bucket to limit API Calls
bucket = TokenBucket(40, .5)

api_call_success = False

while not api_call_success:
    if bucket.tokens < 1:
        sleep(.5)
    else:
        [... do an API call ...]
        bucket.consume(1)
        api_call_success = True
```

This works for my local scripts, but it won't work for my Google App Engine hosted application where there may be multiple tenants, and multiple sessions occurring at once.

I have been trying to research the best way to handle this rate limiting, and presently was going to try to constantly write each users/stores request response header to memcache so that I could always check the 'x-shopify-shop-api-call-limit' to see what the previous call limit (and time of the call) was. So I tried something like this:

```
    fill_rate = .5
    capacity = 40   

    # get memcache key info
    last_call_time = memcache.get(memKey+"_last_call_time")
    last_call_value = memcache.get(memKey+"_last_call_value")

    # Calculate how many tokens should be available
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    delta = fill_rate * ((now - last_call_time).seconds)
    tokensAvailable = min(capacity, delta + last_call_value)

    # Check if we can perform operation
    if tokensAvailble > 1:
        [... Some work involving Shopify API call ...]
        # Do some work and then update memcache
        memcache.set_multi( {"_last_call_time": datetime.datetime.strptime(resp_dict['date'], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'), "_last_call_value": resp_dict['x-shopify-shop-api-call-limit'].split('/',1)[0]}, key_prefix=memKey, time=120)
    else:
        [... wait ...]
```

**Can anyone recommend a better way to manage this rate limiting?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I essentially have the same logic as you (using Redis), however instead of doing this inline everywhere, I've monkey patched `shopify.base.ShopifyConnection` like so:

```
from time import sleep
from django.conf import settings
from pyactiveresource.activeresource import formats
from pyactiveresource.connection     import (
    Connection,
    ConnectionError,
    ServerError,
)
import shopify


class ShopifyConnection(Connection, object):
    response = None

    def __init__(self, site, user=None, password=None, timeout=None,
                 format=formats.JSONFormat):
        super(ShopifyConnection, self).__init__(site, user, password, timeout, format)

    def consume_token(uid, capacity, rate, min_interval=0):
        # Your rate limiting logic here

    def _open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        uid = self.site.split("https://")[-1].split(".myshopify.com")[0]
        self.response = None
        retries = 0
        while True:
            try:
                self.consume_token(uid, 40, 1.95, 0.05)
                self.response = super(ShopifyConnection, self)._open(*args, **kwargs)
                return self.response
            except (ConnectionError, ServerError) as err:
                retries += 1
                if retries > settings.SHOPIFY_MAX_RETRIES:
                    self.response = err.response
                    raise
                sleep(settings.SHOPIFY_RETRY_WAIT)


shopify.base.ShopifyConnection = ShopifyConnection
```

You'll want this code to live in a file within your app's directory, and then import the file into your app's `__init__.py`. This way, I can write the rest of my code without worrying about any rate limiting logic. The only thing you'll have to take care of is to check if the `ShopifyConnection` class changes when you're updating your `shopify` module, and update the monkey patch accordingly. It's not a big issue, as the module doesn't update very often.

(As you can see, I've taken this monkey patch as an opportunity to insert retry logic, as about 1/1000 requests fail for no reason. I'm defining `SHOPIFY_MAX_RETRIES` and `SHOPIFY_RETRY_WAIT` in `settings.py` and pull in the values here.)

Comment: If the front end of your application also calls the Shopify API, does this ever cause responsiveness issues if some backend process uses up all the room in the call bucket at the same time that a user tries to perform an operation? I've read a few threads were people suggest that is a problem.

Comment: Would you be able to further elaborate what rate limiting logic you use in 'def consume_token'? I was going to try to do a calculation based upon the previous response time, but prior to calling consume_token I am calling self.response = none so I don't really have access to this previous call time.

Comment: Regarding your first question: I'm not sure what you mean by using the API from the front-end. To my knowledge, you need to send a request to your server, and then your server makes the API calls. Doing this from the client side would imply security problems. That being said, if the app is ever waiting for more tokens before issuing an API request, it has succeeded in doing exactly what it should be doing. If this ever becomes a big problem, I'd suggest re-evaluating your implementation, and see if you can possibly cut down on API calls.

Comment: Regarding your second question: I unfortunately can't give the details of this function without violating some IP agreements, but I can point you in the right direction. You have access to all the response information from `self.response` right after we call `super()`, however from my testing it seems that the rate limiting is determined by request time and not response time. Therefore, you can do that logic from within the `consume_token` function, as this is right before the request is made; you don't even need to look at the response.

Comment: To account for the time it takes to reach Shopify, you can adjust `rate` and `min_interval` to your needs (implementing `min_interval` as the minimum time between requests). This isn't precise, but I've processed millions of Shopify requests this way and have had no problems.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not the greatest at this portion. How would I access the request from within `shopify.base.ShopifyConnection`? I tried to create Class instance variable to hold my `last_response_time` and `last_response_value` but every time I call a new Django view it creates a new instance of the `ShopifyConnection` class and the instance variables are reset, so I wouldn't be able to track them if the user continued to take action on the site in a new view whilst a process in a task queue also tried to access the API... any thought? Or should I just hire someone to take care of this portion

Comment: Set and get them using memcached.

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't ever need to instantiate `shopify.base.ShopifyConnection` manually. This is done behind the scenes whenever you submit any API call using the `shopify` library.

Comment: Julien, can you check my posted answer to see if you think there might be issues? I think I nearly have it...

Answer (score 0):

Shopify distributes a CLI Ruby gem with rate limiting code. Since Ruby and Python are syntactically close, you should have little trouble reading their code. Since Shopify code is usually written to a high standard, if you pillage their pattern and convert to Python, you should be able to function well on GAE.

Comment: Is this the CLI Ruby gem you are talking about: [link](https://github.com/shopify/shopify_cli)

Comment: Nope.. it is this one.. the CLI for themes... 

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme

and this file

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme/blob/master/lib/shopify_theme.rb

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
from google.appengine.api import memcache
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
from django.conf import settings
from time import sleep

# Store the response from the last request in the connection object
class ShopifyConnection(pyactiveresource.connection.Connection):
    response = None

    def __init__(self, site, user=None, password=None, timeout=None,
                 format=formats.JSONFormat):
        super(ShopifyConnection, self).__init__(site, user, password, timeout, format)        

    def consume_token(self, uid, capacity, rate, min_interval):
        # Get this users last UID
        last_call_time = memcache.get(uid+"_last_call_time")
        last_call_value = memcache.get(uid+"_last_call_value")

        if last_call_time and last_call_value:
            # Calculate how many tokens are regenerated
            now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            delta = rate * ((now - last_call_time).seconds)

            # If there is no change in time then check what last call value was
            if delta == 0:
                tokensAvailable = min(capacity, capacity - last_call_value)
            # If there was a change in time, how much regen has occurred
            else:            
                tokensAvailable = min(capacity, (capacity - last_call_value) + delta)

            # No tokens available can't call
            if tokensAvailable <= min_interval:
                raise pyactiveresource.connection.ConnectionError(message="No tokens available for: " + str(uid))


    def _open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        uid = self.site.split("https://")[-1].split(".myshopify.com")[0]
        self.response = None
        retries = 0
        while True:
            try:
                self.consume_token(uid, 40, 2, settings.SHOPIFY_MIN_TOKENS)
                self.response = super(ShopifyConnection, self)._open(*args, **kwargs) 

                # Set the memcache reference
                memcache.set_multi( {
                    "_last_call_time": datetime.datetime.strptime(self.response.headers['date'], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'), "_last_call_value": int(self.response.headers['x-shopify-shop-api-call-limit'].split('/',1)[0])}, 
                               key_prefix=uid, time=25)
                return self.response    
            except (pyactiveresource.connection.ConnectionError, pyactiveresource.connection.ServerError) as err:
                retries += 1
                if retries > settings.SHOPIFY_MAX_RETRIES:
                    self.response = err.response
                    logging.error("Logging error for _open ShopifyConnection: " + str(uid) + ":" + str(err.message))
                    raise
                sleep(settings.SHOPIFY_RETRY_WAIT)
```

I think I was able to get this going thanks to user Julien. Just want to confirm that there isn't any oversights through testing and feedback.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend raising an error when the tokens are used up, as this is exactly what we are trying to avoid with this monkey patch. Rather, `sleep()` for the needed time to regain a token before sending the next request. I also think that your `min_interval` is something different than what I suggested, and in fact I can't figure out what differentiates it from `capacity` in your implementation.